# Regex to match path that contains wildcards less than 3 levels deep

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a way of matching paths, which contain a wildcard '*' below 3 subdirectories. Just to illustrate some examples:

```
*              <-- match
abc*/def/ghij  <-- match
/abc/*def/ghij <-- match
/abc/def/*     <-- no match
```

My goal is to then use this pattern in a SQL statement like `REGEXP_LIKE`.

I've tried working my way with this regex `^(?:[^/*]*\/)*([^/]+)$`, but it works in reverse (i.e. not matching when I have wildcards < 3 levels down) and it doesn't seem to consider when the path is only '*' or begins with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use negative look-aheads. Assuming you want the whole whole path first you match any path with `*` with `(.*\*.*)` (0 or more of any character, a wildcard, then 0 or more of any character). To omit those that are too deep use `(?!(\/)[^*/]*\1[^*/]*\1)` where `(\/)` is not repeated 3 times and between the slashes there are no other slashes or wild chars.

```
^(?!(\/)[^*/]*\1[^*/]*\1)(.*\*.*)
```

Comment: Awesome, many thanks for the quick response. And if I don't want to match when my string is only '*'? So in the examples I provided the first line turns to 'no match'.

Comment: add `(?!\*)`  by the first look ahead